# js/jquery not working with ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some js and jquery on page (in external file), and everything is working fine on the pageload. All the effects are working fine. The problem starts when i submit form through jquery and get more js data from the server and append it to the body through jquery. The data itself is jquery and adds HTML to a specified element. Now, anything inside that piece of HTML doesnt trigger previous jquery code. I have to resend the same code again and again with each ajax response. Is this a problem on normal behaviour of the language.

Im a beginner.

Herz the code that works fine before, but doesnt afterwords:

```
$('form').submit( function() {
            switch( $(this).attr('name') )
            {
                case 'ajaxeditbookmarkform':
                alert( '1' );
                case 'ajaxbookmarkform':
                alert( '2' );
            }
            return false;
    });
```

Comment: Didn't understand your meaning. Are you trying to fire some jQuery code on success callback of your ajax call?

Comment: Please provide your html code, the jquery code looks right.

Comment: As akhil says - you need a `break;` after each `case` block - otherwise execution will drop through into following `cases`

Comment: Thanks, you all. I found the answer below. The problem was that the submit event did'nt automatically gets attached with the HTML (forms) fetched through ajax. Many thanks to Rupesh Pawar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) events.....

This method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers when content is dynamically added to a page. See the discussion of direct versus delegated events in the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You missed break statement in case ...

check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zCAEf/)

Answer (score 1):

First off. Yes this is normal behavior. What you could try to do is to use the .live function from jQuery like so:

```
$('form').live('submit', function() {
        switch( $(this).attr('name') )
        {
            case 'ajaxeditbookmarkform':
            alert( '1' );
            case 'ajaxbookmarkform':
            alert( '2' );
        }
        return false;
});
```